# My printer Canon Pixma Ip1800 doesn't work

Tags: drivers, canon, pixma

I've tried everything. I researched on forums. And although I managed to install a driver that doesn't give problems, the printer doesn't respond to my requests.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon lP1800 Series

You can try the following ppa however it seems it hasn't been updated in ubuntu 14.04 first make sure you have the correct ppa. Check at least twice.Then....

Open the terminal under Ubuntu and run these commands to install printer drivers:

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk 

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-lp1800series

    sudo apt-get update
```

Now open "printing" options in the unity or system settings-> drivers->printing

Click add and select the printer.

Ok so if that busted remove the ppa in settings-> software updates and then open a terminal and type:

```
cd /tmp && wget http://www.bagbit.pl/download/canon_ip1800_deb.tar.gz && tar xzf canon_ip1800_deb.tar.gz && sudo canon_ip1800_deb/install.sh
```

This is going to take awhile.... like you might want to go to a movie and done.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: I updated the answer sorry i did have the wrong ppa

Comment: Works!.
I do not know how to thank you. Well, yeah, when you come to Spain a good wine and serrano ham is waiting for you.
Thank you very much and take care.

Comment: You welcome please remember tol click the CHeck MarK to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and got 32 bit drivers to work in my 64 bit machine by installing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0:i386 libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

The 32 bit drivers are still available [here](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/gutenprint)