# I need a Canon Pixma Ip1800 driver for Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, pixma

This is a duplicate, but given links in original post don't work anymore.

I would comment asking for new link, but I do not have 50 reputation...

So only thing I know I can do is to make a new question and hope same people will see it and re-upload that driver...

If there was something else I could do, please tell me what, so that I don't make duplicate next time.

Original post: [My printer Canon Pixma Ip1800 doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740349/my-printer-canon-pixma-ip1800-doesnt-work)

Please do not remove this, or help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try this deb file: http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cnijfilter-common-3.50/cnijfilter-common_3.50-2ubuntu4_i386.deb

It is from the Autor of the last solutionfiles [michael-gruz](http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/).

Comment: I have neither a 14.04 32bit system nor a Canonprinter by myself so I cant test it.

Comment: that is a 10yr old printer: Canon built them to last; we hope the above solution works